# MyBatis with MS SQL is not mapping to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data-jpa, mybatis, mssql-jdbc

I'm using a version of MyBatis 3.4.5+, so according to the documentation (https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers), it should be able to use LocalDateTimeTypeHandler.

These are my columns in SQL Server:

```
  Created DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
  Updated DATETIME2,
```

And this is a part of DTO:

```
private LocalDateTime created;

private LocalDateTime updated;
```

And mapper:

```
    @Select("SELECT * FROM XObject WHERE id = #{someId}")
Optional<XObject> findById(String someId);
```

It's working for all of the fields, but not the LocalDateTime.

Should I use another type? If so, what specific? Maybe add some special annotation to use JSR-310 type handlers?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` does not contain information about the timezone of offset and `DATETIME2` seems to be a timestamp using SQL Server's time zone / offset. Can mybatis map an `Instant` instead or a `ZonedDateTime`/`OffsetDateTime`? If yes, pay attention to the zone or offset that gets mapped...

Comment: To handle `LocalDateTime` correctly, you need to use MyBatis 3.5.1 or later (3.5.5 is the latest) and a recent version of mssql-jdbc. If it still does not work, please explain what exactly happens (e.g. error? unexpected result?).

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
  <artifactId>mybatis-typehandlers-jsr310</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

from : https://github.com/mybatis/typehandlers-jsr310

Hope it will works!